# Preventing AutoCompleteTextView from showing duplicates

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, hashset, autocompletetextview

Take a look at my code below:

```
DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
final ArrayAdapter<String> autoComplete = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
final HashSet<String> hashSet = new HashSet<>();
      //*I cut out the part where I get the data from the database and store it into "hashSet"
autoComplete.addAll(hashSet);
actv.setAdapter(autoComplete);
```

I tried this approach to prevent duplicate items in my ACTV(`AutoCompleteTextView`). However, suggestions no longer appear. It **did** work when I **didn't** first add the retrieved data and store it in `hashSet` and then add it to `autoComplete` but instead directly adding it to `autoComplete`.

How can I solve this?

---

**Edit:** I've noticed something, in the method where I'm retrireving my data...

```
 hashSet = new HashSet<>();
        database.child("AutoCompleteOptions").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot suggestionSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String suggestion = suggestionSnapshot.child("suggestion").getValue(String.class);
                        //Log.d("FBSA",suggestion);
                        hashSet.add(suggestion);
                        for(String s:hashSet)
                            Log.d("FBSA",s);
                }
            }
```

...my `HashSet` gets filled with items. However, when the program EXITS that method, it seems that my `HashSet` is completely CLEARED. What I mean is, in the `onDataChange()` method, when I add:

```
for(String s:hashSet)
   Log.d(TAG,s)
```

I get the list of items normally as I expected. **However**, when I do the for loop OUTSIDE `onDataChange()`, the HashSet is empty, meaning it was cleared. **However, *this is not the same when using `ArrayAdapter`***

Comment: your `hashSet` is empty then

Comment: @pskink But when I add `for(String s:hashSet){
                            Log.d("FBSA",s);`} It proves I have items in it.

Comment: tried `add` instead of `addAll`?

Comment: @pskink isn't `add` just for one string?

Comment: @pskink by `for(int i=0;i<autoComplete.getCount();i++){ Log.d(TAG,autoComplete.getItem(i));}` I have proved that `addAll()` isn't working, since `autoComplete` is empty.

Comment: so, tried `add()` instead of `addAll()`?

Comment: @pskink `add` is for a single string, not a full Set

Comment: and you cannot call it multiple times?

Comment: @pskink Oh, you mean with a `for` loop? I'll try

Comment: @pskink while trying what you said (*which didn't work*) I noticed that after I put everything into the Hashset, everything get's cleared. I'll edit my post and explain further

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/119030/discussion-between-abappletic-and-pskink).

Comment: @pskink I solved it myself. I'll show how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**After hours of research and thinking, I did it.**

After you've gotten your data, before added anything to your `ArrayAdapter` remove all strings that are the same as the one you just got first, THEN add it. This pretty much says:

> "You gave me a KitKat bar? Ok, let me see if I have any KitKat bars,
>   if I do, I'll throw them all out except for the one you're giving me,
>   that way I'll only have one.

Here's the example code:

```
for(String s:myData){
  //This removes all strings that are equal to s in the adapter
  for(int i=0;i < adapter.getCount();i++){
     if(adapter.getItem(i).equals(s)
          adapter.remove(s)
   }
//Now that there are no more s in the ArrayAdapter, we add a single s, so now we only have one
adapter.add(s);
}
```

The above code says: Find all the `s` in the `ArrayAdapter` and remove them, then, add a single `s`. That way, I only have 1 `s`. (Relate this to the KitKat example above).

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue. I think I found a better way. I know this is old, just sharing for next person.

```
for (String s: myData) { 
     if (!adapter.contains(s.getName().toLowerCase)) {
         adapter.add(s.getName());
         }
    }
```